# SAS- Newcomer having trouble setting observations to missing

Tags: sas

Code executes correctly - log doesn't show any errors, ect.
I've tried removing the observations with multiple methods. I can manually delete observations. I am able to add to the dataset, but can't remove with code.

```
Data genes3;
Set genes;
If A6_A8= 28.0507 THEN A6_A8=.;
IF ND3_A8= 0.11936 THEN ND3_A8=.;
IF ND5_A8=0.39961 THEN ND5_A8=.;
IF ND3_ND5= 20.0195 THEN ND3_ND5=.;
Run;
```

[Results Showing no difference in the dataset before running the code and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWawB.jpg)

Comment: Could easily be floating point errors; `A6_A8` might not _exactly_ equal `28.0507` in your dataset, and instead be stored as `28.0507000000000001`. Try `If ROUND(A6_A8, 0.0001) = 28.0507 ....` (using whatever the maximum precision of your input data is for rounding)

Comment: An alternative to rounding is to use `If FUZZ(A6_A8 - 28.0507) = 0 ...` The `fuzz` function rounds the input to the nearest integer if the input is within 1E−12 of that integer, which helps when dealing with floating point comparisons.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you so much!